Critical points of ODEs
In ODE books, for:
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}{y(x)}}{\mathrm{d}{x}}=f(x)
$$
the point $x$ such that $f(x)=0$ is called a critical point.
Consider a different problem:
$$
g(y(x))\frac{\mathrm{d}{y(x)}}{\mathrm{d}{x}}=f(x,y(x))
$$
and let $g(y)$ be such that for some $y_0$, $g(y_0)=0$. Then, one typically requires that $f(x_0,y_0)=0$ where $x_0$ is such that $y(x_0)=y_0$ or probably more precisely, one requires something along the lines (not sure if this is the correct limit:
$$
\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f(x,y)}{g(y(x))}=A
$$
where $A$ is a constant. Is such a point also called a critical point?
What would be a good reference that discusses these types of situations, especially related to numerical approaches to such problems?
